# Trouble with the private key for "myName" is not installed on this mac

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried to validate my xcode project but it cause error that 'the private key for "my name" is not installed on this mac"

Because this project was created by another Mac Computer.And that has broken. So , I can't export this private key to it which I am using .

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should revoke your distribution certificate in your account. So that it ask the `.cer` keyfile in your account again. You can create `.cer` file in your keychain go to `Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority` and give your details that your mail id etc. so that it will create `.cer` file and in `developer.apple.com` you can upload the `cer` file once you revoke your distribution certificate so that it will generate the certificate which can be installed in your system. [image][image]

Comment: In your apple developer account. Create New Developer Certificate